# string remove jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, events, click

```
<div id="minus1">
    <input id="minus1str_1" class="input_box"> -
    <input id="minus1str_2" class="input_box"> =
    <span id="minus1_total"></span>
    <button id="m_cal1" type="button" style="margin-left:100px;">done</button>
</div>
```

if `minus1str_1` enter "abcde" and `minus1str_2` enter "abc" `minus1_total` = "de"

I want to know how to create code with jQuery.

Comment: well this should be done with replace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
and a listener on the button.
What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace()` which will replace the string with `''` so that it will simulate as if it has been subtracted:

```js
$('#m_cal1').click(function(){
  var minus1str_1 = $('#minus1str_1').val();
  var minus1str_2 = $('#minus1str_2').val();
  $('#minus1_total').html(minus1str_1.replace(minus1str_2,''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minus1">
    <input id="minus1str_1" class="input_box"> -
    <input id="minus1str_2" class="input_box"> =
    <span id="minus1_total"></span>
    <button id="m_cal1" type="button" style="margin-left:100px;">done</button>
</div>
```

If you want to subtract all the occurrences then use global replace like:

```js
$('#m_cal1').click(function(){
  var minus1str_1 = $('#minus1str_1').val();
  var minus1str_2 = $('#minus1str_2').val();
  $('#minus1_total').html(minus1str_1.replace(new RegExp(minus1str_2, 'g'),''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minus1">
    <input id="minus1str_1" class="input_box"> -
    <input id="minus1str_2" class="input_box"> =
    <span id="minus1_total"></span>
    <button id="m_cal1" type="button" style="margin-left:100px;">done</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much !!!!

Comment: @ctmong glad to help :)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: @ctmong yes sure please. If its a bigger question you can create a new question

Comment: I wanna know what to do if one more input is added to the code I asked
ex) string - string - string  / add: `var minus1str_3 = $('#minus1str_3').val();`

Comment: You can do `minus1str_1.replace(new RegExp(minus1str_2, 'g'),'').replace(new RegExp(minus1str_3, 'g'),'')`

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/67a8qb5g/143/) it doesn't work ;( am i wrong code?

Comment: @ctmong it works https://jsfiddle.net/67a8qb5g/145/ you are using incorrect regex as `new RegExp(minus2str_2, 'dd')`. It should be `new RegExp(minus2str_2, 'g')`

Comment: thank you so much. I learn a lot from you. thank you